# Is Hamiltonian path solvable in nondeterministic log space?

Tags: graph-theory, np-complete, hamiltonian-path

Is Hamiltonian path solvable in nondeterministic log space?

Vertices are notated in base 2

Keep two counters

First counter is current vertex

Second counter implies max vertex encountered in sequence. 0 means 1 is not encountered. 1 means 1 is encountered. 2 means 2 and 1 is encountered. etc.

Random walk starting at vertex 0

Hamiltonian path if and only if second counter equals max vertex.

Clearly log space.

Is this correct?

—-

Comment: Please clarify, how your algorithm works - specifically, which transitions are possible.

Comment: @mihaild The algorithm is not correct. I realized this. I posted an answer. It was deleted. I posted a more detailed answer.

Comment: @mihaild Regarding transitions: The first counter (assume it's currently `a`) can have its value changed to `b` if and only if `ab` is an edge. The second counter always increments by 1 when the first counter changes Both counters are initialized to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

No, this algorithm is not correct.

It decides the existence of a walk from vertices `0` to `n-1` of length `n`.

Comment: Doesn't the algorithm simply decide the existence of any walk from $0$ to $n-1$? If I get from $0$ to $n-1$, the second counter will equal $n-1$, whether or not all the other vertices have been visited.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Correct.